# Button side by side with same size

Tags: html, css

What I want is two buttons on the same line.
The first one on the very left.
The other one of the very right.
Both must have the **exact same size, based on the longest text of both** (text size may vary in each of them)

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Little text (very left)</button>
  <button>This text is way more long than the other (very right)</button>
</div>
```

I tried both flex and grid but without success.
Any idea?

Comment: You will need javascript for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using `flex` and javascript:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var btn1= document.getElementById("btn1");
  var btn2= document.getElementById("btn2");
  var maxWidth = btn1.offsetWidth; 
  if(maxWidth<btn2.offsetWidth)maxWidth=btn2.offsetWidth;
  maxWidth+=1;
  btn1.style.width = maxWidth+"px"; 
  btn2.style.width = maxWidth+"px"; 
});
```

```css
.container {
  display:flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;   
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button id="btn1">Little text (very left)</button>
  <button id="btn2">This text is way more long than the other (very right)</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That does not answer the question. This is just the same as width:50%. I need to size them based on the longest text.

Comment: @user1372445 Check if the new edit solves your problem.

Comment: it should work yes. But I am looking for a css solution

Answer (score 1):

Here you should use JavaScript. First, get buttons widths, compare them and then make equal the less button to bigger.

```js
let btn = document.querySelectorAll('button')

if(btn[0].offsetWidth > btn[1].offsetWidth) {
    btn[1].style.width = `${btn[0].offsetWidth}px`
} else {
    btn[0].style.width = `${btn[1].offsetWidth}px`
}

console.log(btn)
```

```css
.container {
    width: 800px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <button>Little text (very left)</button>
    <button>This text is way more long than the other (very right)</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a fix larger `width` so that content of 2nd button can be easily contained because 1st one will not create problem .

`float` can be used to direct to extreme left/right but it is not recommended

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
button{
width:350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button>Little text (very left)</button>
  <button style="float:right">This text is way more long than the other (very right)</button>
</div>
```

You can use `display: flex` also like in below snippet :

```css
.container {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between
}

button {
  width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<!--span tag is used which act as container for button to preserve the button default height can remove it to span the whole height of container by button-->
  <span><button>Little text (very left)</button></span>
  <span><button>This text is way more long than the other (very right)</button></span>
</div>
```

Width of your button can be based on the one which has `max-text` by using method in below snippet

> Here used 3 buttons (can use any number)  with different length to demonstrate how function works you can put buttons at extreme ends using above methods so not included here

```js
function widthBtn() {
  var reed = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0].getElementsByTagName("BUTTON");

  let lengths = Array.from(reed).map(e => e.innerHTML.length);
  let max = Math.max(...lengths);

  for (let i = 0; i < reed.length; i++) {
    if (reed[i].innerHTML.length == max) {
      var maxWidthBtn = reed[i].offsetWidth;
    }
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < reed.length; i++) {
    reed[i].style.minWidth = maxWidthBtn + "px";
  }
}
widthBtn();
```

```css
.container {
  width: 2000px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <!--span tag is used which act as container for button to preserve the button default height can remove it to span the whole height of container by button-->
  <button>This text is way more long than the other (very right)</button>
  <button>Little text text is way more long than the other (very right) (very left)</button>
  <button>Little text (very left)</button>
</div>
```

You can't use CSS to know elements length or width , it is only for styling purpose . Use **JavaScript** language which is suitable to come up with solution

Comment: That does not answer the question. I don't want to use fixed width. I need to size them based on the longest text (that may vary)

Comment: If you need to change width based on the longest text than I have provided a code for that purpose in **JavaScript** .

Comment: You can't change that by simply using **CSS** because **CSS** = **Cascading Style Sheets** and you have to know the highest length of button and then change width based on that which is not possible by using **CSS** . CSS purpose is to style the webpage not to run a function . To run a function you must have to use other eligible language , here I used **JavaScript** you can use any other also like **jQuery** or **Python**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by changing a little in your code.

```
.container {
    border: 2px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
```

Here I am just making the outer container flex and setting the flex direction row. This will set both buttons in a single row. Now just add:`justify-content: space-between;` and both the buttons will be aligned as you want.

By the way there is also an alternate method through which you can do this work.
Just give unique id to both the buttons.

```
 <div class="container">
  <button id="btn1">Little text (very left)</button>
  <button id="btn2">This text is way more long than the other (very right)</button>
</div>
```

Now set the `float` property to `left` and `right`

```
#btn{
      float: left;
  }
  #btn2{
      float: right;
  }
```

I think it should work now. Thanks

Comment: That does not solive the size issue. I already know how to position them.

Comment: explain your question clearly..